# OpenModelica algorithmic debugger doesn't display variable values

Tags: debugging, gdb, modelica, openmodelica

I am struggling with debugging a model due to missing variable information in the Algorithmic Debugger's Local Browser window. As far as I understand the OpenModelica manuals, when setting a break point within an "algorithm" section and starting the debugger, all variables declared within the model's namespace should automatically show up in the Locals Browser.
Whichever of my own, but also the Modelica Std. Lib. example models I try, the Locals Browser window is always blank.

[image]

Is there a way of turning it on manually? Or do I need to add variables somehow manually? Or do I need to set any specific compile flags?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Stephan

Using: OpenModelica 1.17.0~dev-300-g00309fd on Ubuntu, with Modelica Lib. 3.2.3

Comment: Did you compile the model with `-O0 -g`? If you didn't, it's likely that the debugger cannot see the information

Comment: I think -O0 -g should happen automatically if you press "Simulate with Algorithmic Debugger" arrow. Are you breaking in an algorithm section of a function?

Comment: I just tried these flags. Same situation. The break point is inside a sub-model's algorithm section, which is a model class and not a function.

Comment: I am interested in seeing the the output of "Debugger CLI". The easiest way to share this information is to send us the "omeditdebugger.log" file from the tmp directory.

Comment: You cannot break in an algorithm section, only in functions. Modelica algorithms are mostly seen as equations by the compiler (relations will generate events, etc). If you can put that algorithm in a function and call that function in the algorithm section you will be able to break in the function.